# macOS wants to make changes. Enter an administrator's name and password to allow this

Tags: macos, keychain

My macbook periodically asks for my password when waking up. It always looks like below and usually has a skype icon (but not always, i think). Is there a way to find what event is causing this using console.app? I've already tried some standard steps to reset the keychain.

[image: permissions alert]

Comment: Hello, can you let us know what happens when you enter in the admin credentials and click Allow?

Comment: Also can you try changing the admin users password, reboot and let us know of results?